Docker fails to run ocelot after create ocelot's container in .NET 6
Here is my program.cd:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;
using Ocelot.Cache.CacheManager;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
IConfiguration configuration = builder.Configuration;

new WebHostBuilder()
.UseKestrel()
.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
    config
        .SetBasePath(hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile($"ocelot.{hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true)
        .AddJsonFile("ocelot.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
})
.ConfigureServices(s => {
    s.AddOcelot()
    .AddCacheManager(x => x.WithDictionaryHandle()); ;
})
.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
{
    logging.AddDebug();
    //logging.AddConsole(); //Got Error when Activated
    logging.AddConfiguration(configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
})
.UseIISIntegration()
.Configure(app =>
{
    app.UseOcelot().Wait();

})
.Build()
.Run();

And here is my ocelot.development.json:
 {
  "Routes": [
    // Catalog API
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v1/Catalog",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "catalog.api",
          "Port": "80"
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/Catalog",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT" ],
      "FileCacheOptions": {
        "TtlSeconds": 15
      }
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v1/Catalog/{id}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "catalog.api",
          "Port": "80"
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/Catalog/{id}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "DELETE" ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v1/Catalog/GetProductByCategory/{Category}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "catalog.api",
          "Port": "80"
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/Catalog/GetProductByCategory/{Category}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ]
    }

  ],

  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:5010" 
  }
}

This is ocelot config on docker-compose.override.yml:
  ocelotapigw:
    container_name: ocelotapigw
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    depends_on:
      - catalog.api
      - basket.api
      - discount.api
      - ordering.api
    ports:
      - "8010:80"

And here is the ocelotapigw container log:
2024-04-01 10:56:08 Hosting environment: Development
2024-04-01 10:56:08 Content root path: /app
2024-04-01 10:56:08 Now listening on: http://[::]:80
2024-04-01 10:56:08 Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

I got this error whenever trying to access this address: http://localhost:8010/Catalog

This page isn't working - localhost is currently unable to handle this request
HTTP ERROR 502

On the local mode for ocelot, when I run using Visual Studio & Kestrel, everything is working, but it's not working when I'm using the Docker container!
